# R and parallel computing

Tags: r, parallel-processing

First of all, I know that there are specific packages to do parallel computing with R such as snowfall and that I should use them to do parallel computing. Since an instance of the R program uses only a core of the processor, I've done the following experiment:

- I've opened one instance of R and I've fitted two times the same regression model and I've tracked the time elapsed with system.time()
- I've opened two instances of R and I've fitted the same regression model one time simultaneously and I've tracked the time elapsed with system.time()

To my surprise, it seems that using only an instance of R is more advantageous than using two instances of the program. Since R uses only one core and I have a multicore processor, how is this possible? Thank you.

EDIT:
This is not the code I used but the results are the same:
First of all create the data:

```
x=rnorm(10^8)
dataset=data.frame(V1=x)
write.table(dataset,file="dataset.txt")
rm(list=ls())
```

Close the R instance, open a new R session, import the data and run this code:

```
dataset=read.table("dataset.txt")
system.time(sort(dataset[,1]))
```

To do the task twice just call the function twice:

```
system.time(sort(dataset[,1]))
system.time(sort(dataset[,1]))
```

Comment: How you measured the elapsed time? Single core takes`system.time(for(i in 1:2)sort(dataset[,1]))` and 2 parallel instances should take about `system.time(sort(dataset[,1]))`

Comment: I've measured time as you've just said